# "Learn More" button overlaps text in Documentation banner

Tags: bug, documentation, google-chrome

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the "Learn More" button is overlapping some text in the Documentation banner.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I went to the Stack Overflow Documentation page it was working fine. It is probably a glitch caused by your browser.

To solve this: Delete browser history to clear up space, reload the page or use a browser like Chrome or Firefox.

I think that you should be fine. Don't worry.

Comment: Well, obviously it is a _"a glitch caused by your browser"_. That is why OP is reporting it here. Telling somebody to use a different browser rather than fixing the bug is not an answer.

Comment: A glitch is not something that is permanent. It is not the problem with the code. If it is a "glitch caused by the browser" then all you do to fix it is go to a new one. A glitch and a bug are very different. @Turnip Please explain what was so wrong about saying a glitch is not a huge problem and is easily fixable

Comment: This answer does not make any kind of sense.